# How to use a single pin for input/output on the 8051 with assembly language?

Tags: assembly, 8051

I'm making a simple House Alarm circuit and need to program it in assembly. P0 and P1 are motion sensors while P2.0 = enable/disable, P2.1 = reset, P2.2 = alarm. I'm new to this so please excuse any obvious mistakes.

```
 Created:   Fri Nov 19 2021
 ; Processor: 80C31
 ; Compiler:  ASEM-51 (Proteus)

  $NOMOD51
  $INCLUDE (8051.MCU)

  ; Reset Vector
  org   0000h
  setb P2.0
  setb P2.1
  setb P2.2
  org   0100h


  
;P2.0 = Enable/Disable
;P2.1 = Reset
;P0 = 8 sensors
;P1 = 8 sensors
;P2.2 = Alarm

;Source Code
MOV P2.0, #1
MOV P2.1, #1
MOV P2.2, #0

  jmp SWITCH
START: 
  MOV A, P0
  CJNE A, #0, ALARM
  MOV A, P1
  CJNE A, #0, SWITCH
    
 ALARM:  
  MOV P2.2, #0
  MOV A, P2.1
  CJNE A, #0, SWITCH

 SWITCH: 
  MOV A, P2.0
  CJNE A,#0, START
 jmp START
  
  END
```

[image: This picture]

Comment: So what is your question/problem?

Comment: It’s not in the least obvious how the title of your question relates to the body. Please explain in detail what the problem is, i.e. what your question really is.

Comment: @Jester Basically I want to use any 3 pins to output or input a 1 or 0.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] and read "[ask]" to learn how this site works. -- "_Basically I want to use any 3 pins to output or input a 1 or 0._" OK, and what has this issue to do with the sensors and the source you show? Please [edit] your question and clarify the real problem. You might want to present a [mre]. -- BTW, your code looks quite erroneous, for example that conditional jump `CJNE ..., SWITCH` right before the target lable `SWITCH`. If taken or not, the controller continues at `SWITCH`.

Answer (score 1):

For manipulating with single pin you can use instructions:

- CLR bit
- SETB bit
- CPL bit
- JB  bit, label
- JNB bit, label

for testing single bit of accumulator you can use instruction:

- JB  ACC.x, label
- JNB ACC.x, label

For example:

```
clr   P2.2             ;turn led off
setb  P2.2             ;turn led on but this is wrong connected LED to pin
jnb   P2.0, disabled   ;jump to disabled if P2.0 level is low
jb    P2.1, alarmReset ;jump to alarmReset if P2.1 level is high
mov   A, P1
jb    ACC.0, sensorP1_0Active ;jump if sensor on P1.0 send high level
```

Pin driver for LED on P2.2 can provide very low current less than 0.5mA in your schematics. You should reverse LED and add resistor for limit current.